# Django Rest Framework gives error: You do not have permission to perform this action

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following [this](https://riptutorial.com/django-rest-framework/example/30993/api-key-base-request-authentication) tutorial to check whether `api_key` header exist or not. The example seems for authentication purpose and I am unable to figure out how to fix it. When I access the API endpoint I get an error:

```
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

*permisson.py*

from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

```
class Check_API_KEY_Auth(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # API_KEY should be in request headers to authenticate requests
        api_key_secret = request.META.get('API_KEY')
        if 'api_key' in request.headers:
            api_key_secret = request.headers['api_key']
            if api_key_secret == 'adnan':
                print('FOUND')

        return api_key_secret == 'you'
```

`views.py`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import App
from .serializers import AppSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .permissions import Check_API_KEY_Auth


class AppView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = App.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (Check_API_KEY_Auth,)
    serializer_class = AppSerializer

    def show(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

I do not need user auth, all I ned to check API_KEY exist or not, if yes then query against db in a table and return results.

Answer (score 2):

A permission is granted by `django-rest-framework` if all permissions in `permission_classes` return `True`, if any one in the list return `False` then permission is denied

After looking at `Check_API_KEY_Auth` class the only case when this will return `True` is when `API_KEY=you` in the URL, otherwise it will always return `False` and that's why when there is no `API_KEY` in URL it gives this error msg.

The one in the tutorial is the shortest one, it returns the output of `api_key_secret == settings.API_KEY_SECRET` directly to the view which is only yields to `True` or `False`